# Run MongoDB commands from C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, drop-database, runcommand

I want to be able to run any MongoDB command from C#.  I know that this can be done. I start with a simple example, instead of using the `dropDatabase` method from the C# driver I am trying to drop a database using the `db.runCommand` method as follows.

I have tried in two ways, passing the command as a string and also passing the command as a `BsonDocument` but nothing is working and I don't have any clues where I'm wrong even after researching on the internet I cannot find a suitable example.

I'm having a really hard time to identify why this piece of code is not working.

Command passed as a **string**:

```
database.RunCommand<string>("{dropdatabase : 1}");
```

Command passed as a **BSON document**:

```
var command = new BsonDocument { {"dropdatabase", "1" } };
var execute = database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
```

Comment: What is the result returned when you execute the command? It looks like you aren't using the proper case in your code examples: the command is `dropDatabase`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dropDatabase/. With the all-lowercase example your code would likely get an error like `"no such command: dropdatabase"`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `JsonCommand` like this:

```
var command = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>("{ dropDatabase: 1 }");
db.RunCommand(command);
```

or use a `CommandDocument` like this:

```
var command = new CommandDocument("dropDatabase", 1);
db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
```